# How to get Facebook user ID, post images on user's wall after changes?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, permissions

Years ago I've developed apps for *Facebook*, but now seems not working old method to get user's information (id, name, etc) and post data on user's wall.

I've used like this, but for now It returns me blank screen:

```
require_once('FacebookAPI/Facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'xxxxx',
        'secret' => 'xxxxx',
    ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($user) 
    {
        try 
        {
            #Code below to post data on user's wall
            # Photo Caption
            $photoCaption = 'Just used app';
            $imageUrl = ('http://example.com'); // Example URL
            $link = ('http://www.facebook.com/page/app_xxxx?ref=ts');

            # Post Data for Photos API
            $post_data = array(
              'message' => $photoCaption,
              'link' => $link,
              'caption'   => 'Caption text'
            );
            $apiResponse = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $post_data);
            ?>
            #Code below to show app  
            <html>
            <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <center>
               // link to my app
            </center>
            </body>
            </html>
            // Code below to get user's information (name, id)
            <?php
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            $coded = $_REQUEST['code'];
            $name = $user_profile['name'];
            $id = $user_profile['id'];
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        } 
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
        {
            $user = null;
            error_log($e);
        }
    } 
    else 
    {   # Code below to get access from user
        $redirectUri = 'http://www.facebook.com/mypage/app_xxxx?ref=ts';
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
            'scope' => 'publish_stream,photo_upload',
            'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri
        ));
        echo("<script>top.location.href = '" . $loginUrl . "';</script>");
    }
```

Could someone help me out to get successfully user's name, id?

Comment: Go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs and read the documentation. A lot of things have changed in years

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Hope you have downloaded latest php-sdk, you have appid,app des

```
 include_once "php-sdk/src/facebook.php";
 $app_id = 'your app id';
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'your app id',
  'secret' => 'your app secret'
 ));

 $user = $facebook->getUser();
 if ($user) {
      $me = $facebook->api('/me');
      $name= $me['name'];
      $fid=$me['id'];
 }
 else
 {
       $loginUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . 
       $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($app_url) . "&scope=email";
       echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl  . "'</script>");
 }
```

Comment: That is not using the latest SDK.

Comment: It's very good, that because now I read that new SDK only from PHP 5.4 and my server using 5.3. So I have no chances to use new SDK. Going to check.

Comment: With your code I got error: `The parameter app_id is required`

Comment: did you put your app_id , $app_id = 'your app id'

Comment: Really, time to sleep, missing things like that... Now strange thing happens, poped up windows with `Give permissions`, I gave It and It started reloading page. Like a loop for reloading. Maybe that because I set `$app_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/myPage/app_xxxxxxx?ref=ts';` Shouldn't It show my app (from `if ($user) { ... link to my app }` part) after I gave permissions?